# How to inspect every request (including request body) with fastapi?

Tags: python, middleware, fastapi

I would like to create a middleware that authorizes every request based on its url, headers and body ([OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)). To do that I created a custom request and custom route class. [It is the advised way if one wants to manipulate the request body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/). Firstly, I tried to override the `.json()` method and do the authorization there, however, not every request handler calls the `.json()` method, so that is not a possible solution. Then I decided to create a custom method on the request that will do the authorization and call it from a custom middleware. The issue is that the middleware receives a plain request, which does not have the `.is_authorized` method,  rather than the subclassed request.

### Minimal example:

```py
import json
from typing import Callable, Any

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel


def some_authz_func(request: Request, body: Any) -> bool:
    print(vars(request), body)
    return True


class MessageModel(BaseModel):
    message: str


class AuthzMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        await request.is_authorized()
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response


class AuthzRequest(Request):
    async def is_authorized(self) -> bool:
        try:
            json_ = await super().json()
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            json_ = None
        return some_authz_func(self, json_)


class AuthzRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            request = AuthzRequest(request.scope, request.receive)
            return await original_route_handler(request)

        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI(route_class=AuthzRoute, middleware=[Middleware(AuthzMiddleware)])


@app.get('/')
async def no_body():
    return JSONResponse(content={'no-body': True})


@app.post('/')
async def some_body(body: MessageModel):
    print(body)
    return JSONResponse(content={'body': True})
```

### Raised exception

```
  File ".virtualenvs/tempenv-416e126962124/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File ".virtualenvs/tempenv-416e126962124/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 68, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
  File "main.py", line 23, in dispatch
    await request.is_authorized()
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'is_authorized'
```

### Dependencies

```bash
$ pip freeze
anyio==3.6.1
click==8.1.3
fastapi==0.79.0
h11==0.13.0
idna==3.3
pydantic==1.9.1
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.19.1
typing_extensions==4.3.0
uvicorn==0.18.2
```

Comment: Any reason for not using a dependency configured as a required dependency on the FastAPI app object? It doesn't seem like you're actually rewriting the request itself, and if you need those values somewhere in your views you can refer to the dependency that provides the value there as well? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/

Comment: How would you specify the url, headers and body to the dependency? They are not valid pydantic types. I tried to create a dependency like this, `async def some_authz_func(body: Body, headers: List[Header]):` and it fails with this exception `fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <function Body at 0x7f4f97a5cee0> is a valid pydantic field type
`. And even if it worked, how do you get the url from it?

What do you mean by that I'm not rewriting the request object? In the `AuthzRoute` is every Request object wraped in `AuthzRequest`.

Comment: You are right, the dependency works. I needed to pass the Request object to the dependency function rather than try to get the Body and Headers from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by using [dependency injection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) and [applying it to the app object](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/) (Thanks @MatsLindh). The [dependency function can take a `Request` object](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#use-the-request-object-directly) and get the ulr, headers and body from it.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends

async def some_authz_func(request: Request):
    try:
        json_ = await request.json()
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        json_ = None
    print(vars(request), json_)


app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(some_authz_func)])
```

### Whole working example

```py
import json

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel


async def some_authz_func(request: Request):
    try:
        json_ = await request.json()
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        json_ = None
    print(vars(request), json_)


app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(some_authz_func)])


class MessageModel(BaseModel):
    message: str


@app.get('/')
async def no_body():
    return JSONResponse(content={'no-body': True})


@app.post('/')
async def some_body(body: MessageModel):
    print(body)
    return JSONResponse(content={'body': True})
```